# Version control server setup

Tags: ios

I'm new to programming and would like to set up some kind of version control.  I'm not sure how all this works.

I'm thinking that i would need to set up some remote server to check code in and out of so that if something happens to my computer i don't lose the code.

What i don't understand is if there are websites over there that offer free hosting for the repository or how does that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [github.com](http://github.com). You can have there free git (famous version control system) hosting up to 300MB (i think it's 300) of source code.
I think github has also payed account where you can have private/non-public-visible repositories.

And maybe also take a look at [bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org).

What i do:
I'm using [gitosis](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gitosis) on a own server.
With gitosis you can build you own git remote (server).
But this solution requires a root server which cost around 70UDS/month.
With your own server you are independent and you don't have to place your code on other servers.

Comment: Thanks.  Would it be possible to set something up with hosting companies that offer free hosting?  I mean could you use something like gitosis or something like that to set up version control on one of those websites that offer free hosting.

Comment: No. To install gitosis you need at least ssh access and if I'm not wrong root privileges. So you won't be able to install it on a "normal" PHP/etc. webhost.